# How to stop KDE "THE PANEL ONLY"?

Tags: linux, kde, plasma, plasma5, panel

I'm trying to stop the KDE Panel, for use my own panel for example Gnome Panel, Lxpanel or other, then i need stop it or disable permanent before run my gnome panel or lxpanel, to prevent errors, how i can do work it?.

example of what i need:

```
killall kde-panel
```

or:

```
killall plasma-panel
```

or:

```
service plasma-panel stop
```

Or where i can find the config file to set kde panel to disabled?

**note: Im using ubuntu or debian...**

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the graphical user interface?

If you haven't locked your widgets, click on ☰ normally found at the end of the Plasma panel, and then on *More Settings*. You'll now see an option to *Remove Panel*.

[image: Removing Panel]

If you have locked your widgets, ☰ won't be available in the panel. Click on a free space on your desktop and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> followed by <kbd>L</kbd> to make ☰ visible.

Of course, you may want to add the appropriate command to your Autostart to ensure you'll have the panel of your choice available on start up.

Answer (score 2):

To everyone who despite deleting panels via graphical interface can't get rid of them (they appear again after reboot) as was in my case. You can use this script:

```
for (i = 0; i < panelIds.length; i++) { //search through the panels
    panel = panelById(panelIds[i])
    if (!panel) continue;
    
    panel.remove()
}
```

How to run it:
hold `alt + space` and write `desktop console` run it, inside paste my code and execute it.

Useful resource that helped me write this script:
https://userbase.kde.org/index.php?title=KDE_System_Administration/PlasmaDesktopScripting

Different method that i didn't test might include twitching with plasma-desktop-appletsrc file:
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=165564

https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Panels/en

Answer (score 0):

This command will stop the KDE Panels:

```
killall plasmashell
```

And the Composition Manager and Kwin will keep running, without be affected.

Comment: This appears to kill other parts of plasma such as volume buttons.